# Can I still use my own apple ID with its asociated credit card when I'm in a family sharing family?

Tags: family-sharing

I'm thinking of setting up family sharing for our family. We're all adults, so we buy apps for ourselves, but it would be nice if we could share the apps. Will I lose the ability to buy apps with my own Apple ID if I join my family?

Comment: 2021 and this is still the case. Tried to have kid have 'her own' account. Got billed to mine. Even if the kid has their own 'credit card' with their own funds (allowance) -- it gets billed to the family organizer. if you have "family sharing" of apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a workaround: What we have been doing is we have our family account under my sister's credit card. However, the individual members of my family buy Apple Gift cards. This is credited only to the individual family member's account. I usually buy mine at the grocery store, but you can buy them online as well. A little bulky but it works.

Comment: So does your sisters card never get charged? Have you tried not having a card on the organizers account?

Comment: Doesn't work well if you only have one app you want to buy in mind... not to mention it's unclear if there is tax, so I might add $8 to my account only to find I'm short some change...

Answer (score 5):

No. Any apps you buy with your Apple ID will still belong to you. If you leave Family Sharing other family members will lose access to the apps (Mac OS & iOS), movies, TV shows and music that you own.

Any family member's purchase will be charged to the credit card of the Family Organizer.  Gift cards can be used by a family member and they will be charged before the family organizer's credit card. Family Sharing will bill the family organizer's credit card even if other family members have a different credit card on file.

[Here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201079) is a link to Apple's own support document on this.

Comment: That's a bummer. I'd like to make my dad the family organizer (the one sending invitations), but I don't want his credit card to be charged when I buy an app.

Comment: My son and I feel the same way.

Comment: @Mark Could you clarify your 'if they cannot pay for it...' section. You mean it *is* actually possible for a sub account to make their own purchases? I've never tried it here as I don't mind paying for both my partner & I, but just as a general possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Family sharing is required if you wish to share Apple Music using the family plan.  It is a great idea but all purchases of members go onto your card unless they purchase their own iTunes cards and load them on their own account.  Family sharing prefers the creators card over the individual card.  $14.99 to allow all members access to Apple Music is a great deal over the $10.99/mo plan for each one to have an individual plan.  The downside is that if you are the organizer, you are likely going to spend more money for them to save since all of their purchases go onto your card.  I am hoping Apple will provide additional options in the future so you can use the Apple Music Family plan only and individuals cover their own separate purchases.

Comment: Welcome to the future, where Apple still hasn't come to its senses on this issue.